# Changing AMPscript dynamic links after send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

If i am using an AMPscript link in an email (ie a Lookup to a DE where a link is), can I change the link in the data extension after an email has been sent and the link in the delivered email reflect that change? Similar to a joblink but also different I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you cannot. AMPscript is a server-side language, meaning that it’s interpreted at send time on the server and the value used as the link is taken from the DE at that time and rendered in the email’s HTML. Changing the link in the DE after the email has been sent won’t change the already-rendered link inside the email.

See Eliot’s latest video to find out what is possible in terms of changing links post-send: https://youtu.be/eU6PHJ-Fq1c